# Replicating Folder Structure inside the existing folder when updating the model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I have a model with image compression enabled

```
class Course(models.Model):
    def upload_location(instance,filename):
        return "course_images/%s/%s"%(instance.course_name,filename)

    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=300,default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(TeacherProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None)
    course_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    course_cover = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to=upload_location,default="course_images/default.png")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_enrolled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_image = compress(self.course_cover)
        self.course_cover = new_image
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name
```

When I update this model without sending an image from the frontend folder structure gets replicated inside the existing folder. ex:- **Course_images/Science/science.jpg** is the initial folder structure when creating an object with this model. But after updating the model without the image I can see another  **Course_images/Science/science.jpg** inside Course_images. This starts to happen after adding the compression method. Without overriding the save method this works fine. Also if I change the image folder replication is not happening.

View of the updatecourse

```
class UpdateCourse(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Can anyone state a reason for this scenario. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.course_cover:
            im = Image.open(self.course_cover)
            im = im.convert('RGB')
            # create a BytesIO object
            im_io = BytesIO()
            # save image to BytesIO object
            im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=10)

            temp_name = os.path.split(self.course_cover.name)[1]
            self.course_cover.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(im_io.getvalue()), save=False)

            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I updated save method as above. Problem Solved!